# How to log out the user after clicking browser back button in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mouseevent, back, popstate

In my Vue/Typescript project I want to log out the user after he clicks the browser back button.

A very popular solution is using `window.onpopstate`, but I can't use it, because in some other place of my app I'm using `this.$router.go(-1);` (this piece of code is connected to the "Cancel" button, that goes back in a controlled way from the form to the previous page.

I am trying to do this on events, like this (it's in `main.ts` file:

```
function emitMethod() {
  EventBus.$emit(logoutEvent);
}

EventBus.$on(logoutEvent, () => {
  store.commit('logout');
  loginService.logout();
});
```

The problem is: where to put the event (as I say, using it in `onpopstate` event will cause problems in other places in my app.

Is there:

1. any other event (than `onpopstate`, which also handles browser back button or
2. any way to distinguish the back button and router.go() onpopstate events (I have checked what's inside the event, but didn't find any difference)?

Comment: I'd look into if it would be possibly to replace `this.$router.go(-1);` with something more else. Navigating this way does not look 'pretty', as you can probably imagine. Would it be possible, for example, use History API and `replaceState`/ `pushState` instead somehow in your case?

Comment: If you mean: "instead of ```go(-1)``` just check what the previous page was and push there": yeah, I think it would be possible, I'll try it.